# Where can I store my data in Titanium (a nested array)?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I'm using Titanium to develop an Android app.

I have a nested list of data that I'm currently storing in memory upon application startup, with `Titanium.App.Properties.setList`. I know I can encode this with JSON and store it on the phone, instead of memory. Then I can access it only when I need it.

But, where do I store this JSON and how do I access it? I need "random access", since multiple places access the data.

The data is readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti.App.Properties is a persistent store. You only need to write to it when your object changes, not every startup. It is not an in memory store. Further, JSON is a string. So store it with Ti.App.Properties.setString.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand that JSON is a string; I was just using setList before my data was encoded as JSON. Is there any benefit to using JSON over a list? - keeping in mind that I'm only going to write the property when the app starts. It will be readonly from then on.

Comment: If it is read only data, or if it is data that you only generate once and it never changes, then persisting it or translating it back and forth from JSON is a bit unnecessary. If you can store it as a list, then translating it to JSON is also unnecessary. And if it is read only, or completely generated data, then storing it in Ti.App.Properties is unnecessary (just keep it in a variable, or return it from some utility function call).

Comment: One more stupid question: Won't keeping it in a variable (perhaps returned by a utility function) mean that the data is always in memory? Or does Titanium do some optimization tricks to make sure it's only in memory when necessary?

Comment: It's in memory whenever the variable is in memory. Whenever the variable is out of scope and not referenced, it can be garbage collected. If you've got a variable large enough that you're concerned about it threatening your app (like, a 20-30mb variable), then storing it to disk periodically isn't going to help you at all -- in fact, it'll probably hurt your apps performance a ton. At that point, you need to move on to using something more advanced, like a SQLite database (Ti.Database.*) to pull in just the parts that you want.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok, I'll have to do some investigating with the profiling tools to see what works best. Thanks again for your advice.